# Calling function in parent window after closing child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

In my application I need to call a function in the parent window after closing the child window.

The calling is done successfully but in that function I also post a value from a text box in the parent window.

When I post the value from the text box it alerts 'undefined'.

This is the function for the child window after closing the child window:

```
function CallParentWindowFunction()
{
    window.opener.ParentWindowFunction();
    return false;
}
```

This is the function in the parent window:

```
function ParentWindowFunction()
{
    var hidadinfoid = $("#hidadinfoid").val();
    alert(hidadinfoid);
}
```

This alerts 'undefined'.

This is the html input box in parent window:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidadinfoid" value="12" />
```

Where is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidadinfoid` is the value of `name` attribute of input, not its `id`, try this:

```
var hidadinfoid = $("input[name=hidadinfoid]").val();
```

or add an `id` attribute to the input:

```
<input id='hidadinfoid' type="hidden" name="hidadinfoid" value="12" />
```